# Spark retry Attempts config not working from spark session

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to limit the spark Application Attempts. The job is re-submitted in yarn client mode upon failing once.

I am using HDInsight Activity from Azure Data Factory.It is restricting to one attempt if the parameter is passed from ADF.

## #

```
 val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
  conf.set("spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts","5")
  conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts","5")

  val sc = SparkSession.builder
     .master("yarn")
    .config(conf)
    .appName("test")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    //.config("yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts","1")
    //.config("spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts","1")
    .getOrCreate() ##

sc.conf.set("spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts","1")
```

printing the parameters from Console shows
(spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts,1)
(yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts,1)

Answer (score 6):

Check value of `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts` set within Yarn cluster.
Spark spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts can't be more than the value set in yarn cluster. It should be less than and equal to `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts` so that spark apps can respect the yarn settings.